# Querying resources in FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir

If I want to retrieve a list of resources from a FHIR server, is it possible to get a list of the resources without getting the resources themselves.

For example

```
http://baseurl/fhir/profile
```

would get me the first 'page" of profile resources but would return all of the resources. If I just wanted the profile ids and names is that possible?

Comment: It's not possible now. What's the use case?

Comment: What I am attempting to do is query the list of "resources" on a FHIR system so as to be able to drive efficient UI on an app. The overhead of downloading each profile in full as part of the "List" of returned profiles is making the interactions with the FHIR server inefficient.
In FHIR terms I guess this is well within the 20% on its scale of supporting the 80% of use cases.

Comment: But if you don't get the resources, then you'll just have to go back to get them - that's not efficient. So I don't get the use case. When would you need to get the reference, but not want the resource content? You can't show anything....

Answer (score 1):

When retrieving resources, it's possible to request a "summary" of the resource that is lighter weight.  (See http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/query.html#summary).  This wouldn't be as light as just a bare name in most circumstances, but would be much lighter weight than say a full diagnostic image.

Comment: This would be a really nice feature, being able to filter which parameters are added (and possibly add also). How does this work in DSTU-2?

Answer (score 0):

There are two mechanisms for this.  One is with [_summary](http://hl7-fhir.github.io/search.html#summary) and the other with [_elements](http://hl7-fhir.github.io/search.html#elements).

`_summary` = `true` asks for just the elements marked as 'summary' to be included (see each Resource for what these are); there are other possible values too

`_elements` is a comma-separated list of base element names to include for the Resource.  In your case `_elements=id,name` should suffice (if the server supports it).

Comment: I din't see any reference to _elements here http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/2015May/search.html where is that described?

Comment: Info on Elements can be found here : https://www.hl7.org/fhir/search.html#elements

Comment: The appropriate sections of the search specification are linked from _summary and _elements in the answer.